# Dynamically Add and Remove Views from Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, view, dynamic-programming

I'm working on one demo project in that I had create one XML file containing some views like `ImageView`, `EditText`. I'm loading this XML file on `FrameLayout` at runtime. At one point I want to remove all that views and again want to display them, I used `removeView()` method on button click but it does not work for me,,Please tell me the right way to do it..

```
       public class Demo extends Fragment implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener{
    //Declaration of framelayout
    FrameLayout f;
    //Declaration of imageview
    ImageView imageview;
    View view, framelayoutview;
    File file;
    EditText etcardname, EditTextUserName,EditTextUsesrMobNumber,EditTextUsesrEmailID,EditTextUsesrAddress;
    TextView dialogtesting;
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_modify_card ,container, false);
        framelayoutview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frame_layout_data ,container, false);
        captureImageInitialization();
        Initialize();
        return view;
       }
     // Initialization of all views components
     private void Initialize() {
            f=(FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.framelayout);
            Button btneditcardreset=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonresetcard);
            btneditcardreset.setOnClickListener(this);
            Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
            int myInt;
            myInt = bundle.getInt("position");

            imageview=(ImageView)framelayoutview.findViewById(R.id.imageViewicon);
            EditTextUserName=(EditText)framelayoutview.findViewById(R.id.modifycardeditTextusername);
            EditTextUsesrMobNumber=(EditText)framelayoutview.findViewById(R.id.editTextmobilesnumber);
            EditTextUsesrEmailID=(EditText)framelayoutview.findViewById(R.id.editTextemailid);
            EditTextUsesrAddress=(EditText)framelayoutview.findViewById(R.id.editTextaddress);

            imageview.setOnTouchListener(this);
            EditTextUserName.setOnTouchListener(this);
            EditTextUsesrMobNumber.setOnTouchListener(this);
            EditTextUsesrEmailID.setOnTouchListener(this);
            EditTextUsesrAddress.setOnTouchListener(this);
            f.addView(framelayoutview);
           }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
         if(v.getId()==R.id.buttonresetcard){
                 if(framelayoutview.getParent()!=null){
                 f.removeAllViews();
                 }
                 f.addView(framelayoutview);

                 }
      }
```

Sorry to all I forgot to tell that I provided `OnTouchListener` so that I can move the views anywhere in `Layout`. So when I press reset button all `View`s should get move back to their original location means where they were at on first load..

Comment: Can you post the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Updated my code please check,,

Comment: I think you should use ViewSwitcher or ViewFlipper

Comment: Please badly need your help guys..

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

And

`imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

on particular event

Answer (score 0):

If you had added your views dynamically to your `FrameLayout` then you can remove them.

Otherwise, if you showing your views from XML which are exist inside the `frameLayout` XML then you can't remove them but you can hide them from showing by setting `setVisibility(View.GONE)` or `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
         if(v.getId()==R.id.buttonresetcard){
                 if(framelayoutview.getParent()!=null){
                 f.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 }
                 f.addView(framelayoutview);

                 }
      }
```